# for each xslt looks at first item only

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have XML that looks like

```
<data>
<groups name="Group1"/>
<groups name="Group2"/>
<groups name="Group3"/>
</data>
```

when using

```
<xsl:for-each select="/data/groups/@name"><value-of select="/data/groups/@name"/></for-each>
```

I get Group1Group1Group1 not Group1Group2Group3.

Why is for each only looking at the first item and not all three items.

Please provide answers in pure javascript or xslt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xsl you have written selects the name attribute of the first /data/groups for each of the /data/groups in your document. You need to alter your for-each and value-of to the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/data/groups">
   <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<xsl:for-each select="/data/groups/@name">` puts you in the context of `@name`. From this context, you only need to get the current node's value:

```
<value-of select="."/>
```

The way you have it now, you are selecting **all** the `@name` attributes (starting from the root) repeatedly - and (in XSLT 1.0) the `xsl:value-of` instruction returns only the value of the first node in the selected node-set.

Answer (score 2):

I could make it work using the below data (XML) and XSL code

XSLT Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="data/groups">
<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<groups name="Group1"/>
<groups name="Group2"/>
<groups name="Group3"/>
</data>
```

Command

> xsltproc t1.xslt t1.xml

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
Group1Group2Group3
```